# equalTo() method is not working in jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation

```
$('#reg_form').validate({
                onkeyup: false,
                errorClass: 'error',
                validClass: 'valid',
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        //remote: "user_check.php"
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5,
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    },
                    secretQuestion: "required",
                    secretAnswer: "required",
                    emailId: {
                        required: true, 
                        email: true
                    },
                    termsConditions: "required"                 
                },
                messages:{
                    username: {
                        required: "Please enter Username",
                        minlength: "Please enter atleast 5 characters",
                        //remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    confirm_password: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
                        equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                    },
                    secretQuestion: "Please select your question",
                    secretAnswer: "Please enter your secret answer",
                    emailId: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    termsConditions: "Please accept our Terms and COnditions"
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').addClass("f_error");
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').removeClass("f_error");
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $(element).closest('div').append(error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: i have 3 forms in one file. equalTo() is not working. please help me

Comment: that's a lot of down votes with no explanation... be nicer people!

Answer (score 4):

When you set validations via "rules:" you need the "name" of the input and NOT the "id".

So for an input like this:

```
<input type="text" name="password_name" id="password_id></input>
<input type="text" name="confirm_password_name" id="confirm_password_id></input>
```

You should change this in validation:

```
password_name: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5
},
confirm_password_name: {
  required: true,
  minlength: 5,
  equalTo: "#password_id"
}
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any reason why this would fail that is obvious in your code.  Assuming your password input has `id="password"`, everything should be fine.

I created a shortened example demonstrating the `equalTo` rule working:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/MnnE5/

In the future, for questions like these, try to make the smallest possible example that demonstrates your problem - we don't need to have the rules and messages for your whole form, just the 2 password fields.  It would also be helpful to post the relevant HTML form markup.

Comment: @izuriel - lovely link, I will use that in the future :)

Comment: sorry, its coming like this only.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure do not have same id on html page check included templates also

> Note: For test just change id like register_pass and login_pass or just pass1
>         1). if success then id not unique on your html
>         2). if fails then open console for check if jquery or validation js is avail   or not

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's straight up NOT working.

Firefox 17.0.1
jQuery 1.8.3
jQuery Validation Plugin 1.10.0

It's not working if you just use the field name:

...equalTo="password"....

Instead, needs to use id:

...equalTo="#password"....

Comment: Yes, that's how you're supposed to use it. See also the example here in the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo